# jQuery Ajax: get specific object value

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, api

I'm accessing a dictionary REST API using Ajax.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://api.wordnik.com//v4/word.json/cat/definitions?api_key=mykey&includeRelated=false&includeTags=false&limit=1",
  dataType : 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    //called when successful
    alert(data.word);
  },
  error: function(e) {
    //called when there is an error
    console.log(e.message);
  }
});
```

The response:

```
[
  {
    "textProns": [],
    "sourceDictionary": "ahd-legacy",
    "exampleUses": [],
    "relatedWords": [],
    "labels": [],
    "citations": [],
    "word": "cat",
    "text": "A small carnivorous mammal (Felis catus or F. domesticus) domesticated since early times as a catcher of rats and mice and as a pet and existing in several distinctive breeds and varieties.",
    "sequence": "0",
    "score": 0.0,
    "partOfSpeech": "noun",
    "attributionText": "from The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, 4th Edition"
  }
]
```

In my test example I get an alert `undefined` on success. Most Ajax examples I saw use loops but I'm returning one result. How can I extract the `word` and `text` values from the objects?

Comment: +1 to the grammar police for revising my english

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you can see your response starts with `[` and ends with `]`. So your response is an array. Then, inside the array, you get objects (starting with `{` and ending with `}`). So your `data` is an array, which can be accessed with `data[x]` (x being the index), and each member of the selected object can be accessed with the .dot notation: `.word`, `.text` etc. So in your case, if there's only one result, you can do `data[0].word`.

Comment: I am getting output "undefined". What can be the problem??

Comment: im also get  output "undefined".

Answer (score 6):

The response is an object inside of an array. Try `data[0].word`

Answer (score 3):

You want to change the **success** function like this,

```
success: function(data) {
  alert(data[0].word);
}
```

I verified the value coming correctly.

[jQuery AJAX](http://learnhosting.org/jquery-ajax/)