# Extract value from AJAX response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

My php code is as below

```
if ($data = $user->fetch()) 
{
    echo json_encode(array("output" => $data));
}
else
{
    echo json_encode(array("output" => $data));
}
```

My javascript code is as below

```
success: function(response) 
{  
   alert(response);   //shows me [object Object] 

   alert(response[0].output);  // shows me nothing

   alert(response[0]);   //shows me undefined

   alert(JSON.stringify(response));   //shows me  {"output":false} 

    //I would like to get only true or false
}
```

From this post ([jQuery AJAX call returns [object Object]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19584222/jquery-ajax-call-returns-object-object)) I knew that [object Object] is basically an array.

From this post ([jQuery Ajax: get specific object value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11597646/jquery-ajax-get-specific-object-value)) I got below words.

"As you can see your response starts with [ and ends with ]. So your response is an array.

Then, inside the array, you get objects (starting with { and ending with }).

So your data is an array, which can be accessed with data[x] (x being the index), and each member of the selected object can be accessed with the .dot notation: .word, .text etc.

So in your case, if there's only one result, you can do data[0].word."

In this case I should get my expected result using **alert(response[0].output);**

But I am not getting that result. Can anyone help me in this regard ??

Comment: you will get it by response.output.Try this at your javascript. `var data=response.output`.Now `data[0]` is first element of your $data and others.

Answer (score 1):

First off, make sure that you have explicitly set that you're going to receive JSON:

```
dataType: 'JSON',
```

Then try to access them thru this instead:

```
success: function(response) {
    console.log(response.output);
    // kindly open your console browser to see contents
    // i think this is F12
    if(response.output) {
        // do something if true
    } else {
        // do something if false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try also this one:

```
success: function(response) {
   // check your console
    console.log(response);

   //this two will give you same result
    console.log(response.output);
    console.log(response['output']);

 //either of this two
 var output = response.output; 
 var output = response['output']; 

  if(output){
   //code here
  }


}
```