# How to Parse php json_decode data to Jquery Ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

The current problem now is this, the below files are working perfectly well, but when using console.log(data), it prints out the result I wanted very well.

But what I want is to print out the result in a html tag (div) profoundly instead of `console.log()`.

The Php File section

```
<?php

$transaction_id = $_POST['transaction_id'];//get the Transaction ID from Ajax request..

//get the full transaction details as an json from VoguePay
$json = file_get_contents('https://example.com/?v_transaction_id=' . $transaction_id . '&type=json');

$transaction=json_decode($json, true);

//header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($transaction);
```

The Ajax Section...

```
            //clear the display section
            $("#id-input2").html('');
            var data="";
            //call the Ajax Request..
            $.ajax({
                url: "php/fetch_transaction_id.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {transaction_id:transaction_id},
                dataType: "json",

                success: function (vp_response) {
                    $.each(vp_response, function(index, value) {

                        data=(index + ': ' + value);
                        console.log(data);
                    });

                    $('#searchID').val('Data Recieved!');
                },

            });
```

Here is the output for using `console.log();`:

> cur: NGN
>       transaction_id: 5a3182d82a8c6
>       email: talk2awe2004@example.com
>       total_amount: 1016.7000
>       total: 1000
>       merchant_ref:
>       memo: MLM Bank Union Creation
>       status: Approved
>       date: 2017-12-13 20:49:26
>       method: MasterCard & Verve (Naira)
>       referrer: https://www.mlmbank.net/Leaders/create.html
>       total_credited_to_merchant: 1001.450000
>       extra_charges_by_merchant: 16.700000
>       charges_paid_by_merchant: 15.250000
>       fund_maturity: 2017-12-15
>       merchant_id: 3362-0054095
>       total_paid_by_buyer: 1000
>       process_duration: 0.000395

I want same using a html tag instead.

Comment: Post some code, and explain exactly what your problem is.

Comment: Oh...  Oks...  Got that.

Comment: No no, edit your question to include the code. Comment code is very messy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return your array in JSON format with `application/json` content-type

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['transaction_id'])) {

   //get the full transaction details 
   $json = file_get_contents('https://example.com');

   //create new array to store our transaction
   $transaction = json_decode($json, true);

   // Here you can do something with $transaction

   // And return it in JSON format for ajax request
   header('Content-Type: application/json');

   echo json_encode($transaction);
}
```

After that you can get this json in ajax like this

```
<script>
$.get('transaction.php', {transaction_id: 'SOME ID'}, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
</script>
```

jQuery will parse data as javascript object because of `content-type`

Comment: Why `json_decode` if you are just going to `json_encode` after?

Comment: @Eddie for example, if he wants to do something with $transaction data before send

Comment: OK...  Thank you so much. Would try that out once I'm close to my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

If the link you reach out to has raw json, you can simply echo it out :

*PHP*

```
if (isset($_POST['transaction_id'])) 
{
    $TransactionId = $_POST['transaction_id'];

    echo file_get_contents('https://example.com');
}
```

---

You want to add the `success` event handler in your ajax call and then `$.each` through your response. :

*Note : Make sure you have `dataType: 'json'`, this tells jquery to parse the json response.

*Javascript* :

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/yourphpfile.php',
    data : {
        transaction_id: '0'
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success : function(response) {
        $.each(response, function(key, value) {
            console.log(value.whatever);
        });
    }
});
```

Read more on accessing json values : [jQuery Ajax: get specific object value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11597646/jquery-ajax-get-specific-object-value)

Comment: The thing is... Actually, if I should use var_dump($transaction);  only in php,  I would archive what I wanted when $transaction=json_decode($data,  true)  is the return json format . But then, my aim is to make it asynchronous using jquery to receive the json_decode($data)  from the php file...

Comment: So, what are you confused about?

Comment: How to exactly push the json data in form of json_decode($data) to the Ajax success event and then print it

Comment: Why are you decoding the data when sending it to jQuery, how are you going to get the values?

Comment: I'll update my answer with some php if that will clear up some confusion. If you are getting raw json back, there is no need for any other operations to take place. Just echo out the json so jQuery can parse it.

Comment: Actually, I am working on a voguepay notification api.. And the api uses print_f($transaction)  or var_dump($data)  to fetch the results from a given URL in such that the $data=json_decode() ... But I could archive this just using only php..  I just wanted same with jquery/ajax

Comment: I wouldn't mind if you updated your post.. Pls.. As this is a project I am working on and I am really lost on this

Comment: Updated the post.

Comment: OK.. I. Will try this out and definitely give feedback